# Django variables inside for loop inside JS script inside Django HTML template to fill data grid

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, datagrid, for-in-loop

I'm trying to substitute tables with JS Data Grids in my templates by using https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/getting-started/ .
When I copy-paste the example from above website, the data grid loads perfectly. But I want to fill the data grid with variables defined inside a models.py class via a for loop and I don't know how to write this.

models.py class:

```
class Cocktail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    ingredient_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ingredient_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ingredient_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ingredient_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ingredient_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    recipe = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
def cocktail_list(request):
    cocktails = Cocktail.objects.order_by('name') # name of QuerySet
    return render(request, 'inventory/cocktail_list.html', {'cocktails':cocktails})
```

base.html template where data grid should be implemented:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Home</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/inventory.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>

[...]

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 200px; width:500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"></div>
        <script>
            const columnDefs = [
            { field: "name" },
            { field: "ingredient_1" },
            { field: "recipe" }
            ];
            
            // specify the data
*            {% comment %} const rowData = [
            for ({cocktail} in {cocktails}){
                {name: "{{cocktail.name}}", ingredient_1: "{{cocktail.ingredient_1}}", recipe: "{{cocktail.recipe}}"}
            }
            ]; {% endcomment %}*
          // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
            const gridOptions = {
                columnDefs: columnDefs,
                rowData: rowData
            };
            
            // setup the grid after the page has finished loading
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
                new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

the commented out part is the one not working. The table loads but is empty. I've tried the following:

1. what is shown above; JS for loop with probably incorrect handlebars for django variables.
2. 

```
const rowData = [
{% for cocktail in cocktails %}
{name: "{{cocktail.name}}", ingredient_1: "{{cocktail.ingredient_1}}", recipe: "{{cocktail.recipe}}" }
{% endfor %}
];
```

so basically Django for loop inside JS.
None works, I guess because I misuse the handlebars.
Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: now trying
        ```<script>
            const cocktails = {{ cocktails }}
            const name = {{cocktail.name}};
            const ingredient_1 = {{cocktail.ingredient_1}};
            const recipe = {{cocktail.recipe}};
        </script>```
with
            ```const rowData = [
            {{cocktails}}.forEach(cocktail => {
                {name: "{{cocktail.name}}", ingredient_1: "{{cocktail.ingredient_1}}", recipe: "{{cocktail.recipe}}"}
            })
            ];```
also not working...